# Tweet with Spring-Social-Twitter Api inReplyToStatus doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I'm trying to send a Tweet as a response (**reply**) to another tweet that I found via a query.
**But** although I'm calling https://docs.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/social/twitter/api/TweetData.html#inReplyToStatus(long) and pass the correct status Id, the tweet doesn't seem to be a reply to the original tweet.

I'm using `org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE` in a spring boot app and I've also tried the latest Version `1.1.2.RELEASE`, but still doesn't work.

**relevant code**:

```
// Tweet tweet comes from a query
// String statusText is some plain text

final Long inReplyToStatus = tweet.getId();
final TweetData tweetData = new TweetData(statusText);
// try to make it a reply, TODO: doesn't work
tweetData.inReplyToStatus(inReplyToStatus);
// send tweet, but doesn't look like an answer.
final Tweet newTweet = this.twitterTemplateFactory.timelineOperations().updateStatus(tweetData);
```

Do you have any I what's wrong here? Do I have to make it an old-school reply by starting the `statusText` with "@<usernameOfTheOriginalTweet> ..."?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like my guess was correct - you need to start `statusText` with "@<usernameOfTheOriginalTweet>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess was correct. If you want your answer to be shown as a real reply, you have to set the "inReplyToStatus" field **and** start the statusText with "@".

Problem solved.